# Dont want horizontal scroll bar for views

Tags: 7, views

I am using a view called "exhibit" with multiple fields.
I am getting a horizontal scroll bar since the view have multiple fields.
But I don't want the horizontal scroll bar.

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css like this:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where to put the css file in my drupal folder

Comment: Find your current theme, it should be in sites/all/themes, then place it there or in a subfolder css. I guess you already have a css file, add those 2 rows there.

Comment: I am using bartik theme. which is in themes folder itself. Added those two rows in a test.css file, and added this css file to a view. but still getting scroll bar.

Comment: you need to add these rows inside the css rule that describe the specific views element.